# How to apply rice to Awesome WM?

Tags: awesome

I am using Awesome WM on Arch and I want to apply a particular style (rice) to it. I found [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/unixporn/comments/16egajj/awesome_first_rice_first_time_on_endeavouros/) and the author [has uploaded](https://github.com/notAxon/dotfiles) the relevant files to GitHub. How can I use these files to apply the rice?

I copied them to my `~/.config` directory, but what do I need to do now?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us some context. What operating system are you using? What is rice? What are those dotfiles? There is no context in the repository. Please [edit] and clarify what it is you want to do.

Comment: here yougo amigo

Comment: So, you say you copied to your `~/.config` dir, but where? Did you put the files under their respective dirs? Did you make a new subdir? What did you do?

Comment: no, just added them to .config

Comment: Do you know what is a rice ?

Comment: @FBDev it's a kind of grain! (I've been using awesomeWM since ca 2012, and I've never heard the term, so please explain it in your question!)

Comment: No, I don't, that's why I asked "What is rice?" in my first comment.

Comment: ah, that you'll have to ask the poster on reddit, then. It doesn't seem to a term used by anyone else.

Comment: you know any good rice for awesome or i3 that is purple ? could ya help me setting up ?

Comment: @MarcusMüller the term does seem to be used a little. I didn't find it in AwesomeWM's docs, but it does seem to be used by the community and apparently means something like "theme".

Comment: @terdon true, just after I wrote that, I started searching for "ricing", and there's hits for that

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us exactly what you did. "I added them to config" doesn't tell us anything. Presumably, you need to copy each dotfile to overwrite the existing ones in the corresponding directories.